# Applying class to every 3rd list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list, jquery-selectors

I have the following script. At the moment it selects the 3rd item in my list and gives it no margin. The problem is it only does this once, is there a way I can make it happen to every 3rd item in the list? I tried using `.each` but I couldn't get it to work successfully.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contentlist li:eq(2)").css({marginRight: '0'});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nth-child` pseudo-class using `3n` can do this.

```
$( '#contentlist li:nth-child(3n)' ).css({marginRight: '0'});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/gjvpR/

HTML:

```
<ul id="contentlist">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Script:

```
$( '#contentlist li:nth-child(3n)' ).css( {marginLeft: '20px'} );
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Almost there, `nth-child` is a CSS selector so it is one based and that means that `:nth-child(3n)` chooses every third element.

Comment: @muistooshort Not sure what you're getting at with that comment. This and your answer are identical (and this one beat yours by a good 40 seconds). Did I miss an infamous SO lightning edit?

Comment: @Phil: Two lightning edits, it was `nth-child(3)` then `nth-child(3n+1)` and finally `nth-child(3n)`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `nth-child` CSS selector:

```
$("#contentlist li:nth-child(3n)").css({marginRight: '0'});
```

Demo (with colors instead of margins): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/DRCLF/