# JQuery: add class name to every third list item

Tags: jquery

add class name to every third list item. [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950193/applying-class-to-every-3rd-list-item), but addClass() instead css(). i did:

```
 $('ul li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('grey');
```

but not working. what i did wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/6yd5ghh2/2/

Comment: Works perfectly fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6yd5ghh2/1/**

Comment: The css should be like `.grey{..}` and not on `ul li` **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yd5ghh2/3/)**

Comment: @Shaunak D    yes. sorry my bad

Answer (score 0):

In your JsFiddle you're missing the `.grey` class.

Modify your css:

```
ul li {
    color:#000;    
}
.grey{
   color:#AAA;
}
```

This should solve your problem :) .